# How can adapt my data to this linear matrix pytorch optimization method?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, linear-regression

I try my code is not working I'm using a simple  dataset:

```py
epochs = 100 
losses = [] 
for i in range(epochs):   
  y_pred = model.forward(X)   
  loss = criterion(y_pred, y)   
  print("epoch:", i, "loss:", loss.item())      
  losses.append(loss)     
  optimizer.zero_grad()   
  loss.backward()   
  optimizer.step()
```

thanks,

Philippe.

Answer (score 0):

You can load dataset using a custom data generator

```
train_dataset = DatasetGenerator()
```

or loaded data

```
inps = torch.arange(10 * 5, dtype=torch.float32).view(10, 5)
tgts = torch.arange(10 * 5, dtype=torch.float32).view(10, 5)
train_dataset = TensorDataset(inps, tgts)


train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)

epochs = 100 
losses = [] 
for i in range(epochs):   
    for ii, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        y_pred = model(data)  
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(y_pred, target)
        losses.append(loss) 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: I want to add a dataframe of 5 colomns and 2000 rows with csv format